# F5 load balancer rejects a SHA256 encryption algorithm cipher suite?

Tags: security, ssl, tls1.2, sha, f5

I am investigating an issue where two end points are talking over TLSv1.2, the destination being the F5 load balancer. During the client server handshake, the client sent a set of cipher suites out of which the F5 server chose the following cipher to initiate communication :

```
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)
```

The second time the client initiated a handshake the F5 rejected the cipher suite, on checking the cipher suites they did not have SHA384 ciphers:

```
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003c)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc025)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc029)
Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0067)
Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0040)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc004)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc00e)
Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033)
Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0032)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009c)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02d)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc031)
Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009e)
Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x00a2)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc008)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc012)
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000a)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc003)
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc00d)
Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0016)
Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0013)
Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff)
```

I am new to the F5 load balancers, and would like to understand why the F5 does not choose any of the SHA256 encrypted cipher suites. Where is this specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by listing out the supported ciphers from the cipher string configured for that profile using below command

> openssl ciphers *Cipher_string*

And the cipher suites received didn't have single one of them to what BIGIP was configured to accept.

Answer (score 0):

A beginner could follow these steps :

1. Check your F5 BIG-IP version, and then read [K13163](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K13163) to know which cipher suites are supported for this version (follow the links if your version is not in this document). This is necessary to know whether your client and your server have a chance to succeed in the handshaking.
2. Go to [K8802](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K8802) and follow the link *Configuring the cipher strength for SSL profiles* for your F5 BIG-IP version. This will answer your question, on where it is specified.
3. If it's still not enough for you to get the right setup, you need to read [K15292](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K15292) to know how to debug your handshaking problem (some SSL knowledge is required).

Comment: Thank you for sharing resources! this was helpful.